# how to import highcharts with webpack and babel

Tags: javascript, highcharts, ecmascript-6, webpack, es6-module-loader

I use ES6, Babel and webpack stack.

I have installed highcharts by npm (I prefer to use the official highcharts npm repo):

```
npm install highcharts-release --save
```

But, regular import (ES6) doesn't work as expected:

```
import highcharts from 'highcharts';
```

How can I import Highcharts via webpack import?
Can you post a webpack.config.js example (or other way to config the plugins)?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "highcharts" webpackMissingModule @ review-chart.js:2(anonymous function) ....
```

Comment: *"doesn't work as expected"* What do you expect and what happens?

Comment: So if the successful import happens, what is the problem?

Comment: I meant that I expect a successful import, but the import fail and I get an exception

Comment: Do you want to tell us what the exception is or do you want us to guess? The exception message is probably useful for finding out what the issue is.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I've asked this same question about Browserify on the Highcharts page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241358/how-to-import-highcharts-with-webpack-and-babel

Comment: I also need a solution for this.

Comment: @StefanKarlsson, One hacky solution is to just call jQuery as a script in your html, rather than importing it. It seems that the issue has to do with exposing jQuery globally, so you can either mess with your webpack config to do that, or just call it in a script on page load like I did.

Comment: @aioko thanks for the workaround, i know it can be solved this way but it buggs me that it is a hack :) 
And if i understand it right, highcharts should not be dependent on jQuery anymore? or am i wrong? Im using version 4.2.2

But im not using jspm/systemjs instead of webpack: asked a question on the highchart forums:http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/support-es6-module-loading-t34909/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2022 Update**
Highcharts now have an official wrapper for React - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react

> There is a NPM called commonjs-highcharts that solves it. Just run
> `npm i commonjs-highcharts` and import it:
>
> ```
> import highcharts from "commonjs-highcharts"
> ```
>
> Worked for me.

Comment: not working for me... (I mean, the compilation works but I get $(...).highcharts is not a function) the only thing which seems to work is to import it with a require.

Comment: OK I figured out: BowerWebpackPlugin is buggy and doesn't allow to expose jQuery as global anymore, and highcharts use window.jQuery...

Comment: commonjs-highcharts is what finally (after hours of keyboard head slamming) worked for me. couldn't get highcharts-release or any other goofiness to work without doing some webpack config to expose globally

Comment: This will not work anymore. Highcharts has changed, it's standalone framework adaptor has been removed and `commonjs-highcharts` hasn't been updated in half a year.

Comment: As of today, commonjs-highcharts github returns a 404. This didn't work for me. For all you React folks, see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

`npm install highcharts`

The issue I faced with this approach is using other modules in highcharts, such as highcharts-more, map, etc., To overcome this I imported highcharts and the other required modules like this:

```
import highcharts from 'highcharts';
import highchartsMore from 'highcharts-more';
highchartsMore(highcharts);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Though, can you please explain why is `highchartsMore(highcharts);`necessary?

Comment: If you check the `highcharts/modules/map.src.js` file, it takes the Highcharts object as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it, using Webpack v4.16.5 and Highcharts v5.0.11.

webpack.config

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }]
    },
    {
      test: /highcharts.*/,
      loader: 'imports-loader?window=>global&window.jQuery=>$'
    }
    // ...
  ],
  alias: {
    jquery: 'jquery/jquery'
    // ...
  }
},
externals: {
  jQuery: 'jQuery'
},
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    'window.$': 'jquery',
    Highcharts: 'highcharts/highcharts'
    // ...
  })
]
```

main.js 1st option

```
import addMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more'
import addExporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting'
import addOfflineExporting from 'highcharts/modules/offline-exporting'
import addSolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge'
import addDrilldown from 'highcharts/modules/drilldown'
import addTreemap from 'highcharts/modules/treemap'
import addFunnel from 'highcharts/modules/funnel'

addMore(Highcharts)
addExporting(Highcharts)
addOfflineExporting(Highcharts)
addSolidGauge(Highcharts)
addDrilldown(Highcharts)
addTreemap(Highcharts)
addFunnel(Highcharts)
```

main.js 2nd option:

```
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/offline-exporting')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/solid-gauge')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/drilldown')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/treemap')(Highcharts)
require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts)
```

This way, it's both `$(..).highcharts()` and `Highcharts.chart()` usable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Try doing an `npm install highcharts-release`. Then in your JavaScript file do `import Highcharts from 'highcharts-release/highcharts';`. There may be a better way, but that worked for me.

Comment: I not loading jQuery, therefore I want to load the standalone framework too. I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined' error from highcharts.

Comment: Highcharts is missing HighchartsAdapter. To get that going, one way to do this is to add HighchartsAdapter as a plugin. More specifically, in webpack.config.js, try adding `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ HighchartsAdapter: 'highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework'})` under the plugin array.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I don't have any errors during the compilation, but I got `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function` when I load my page. (if I display `$.fn.highcharts` it's `undefined`)

Comment: @gtournie did you ever figure this out. Having the same problem with getting $(...).highcharts to work

Comment: @vernak2539 yes. First, I use the "highcharts-release" package. Then I use the provide plugin: `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 'window.jQuery': 'jquery' })`

Answer (score 2):

Try variations of:

```
require('expose?Highcharts!highcharts');
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
require('expose?Highcharts!highcharts/highstock');
```

If you wander around in `./node_modules/highcharts/...` you might be able to trial-and-error your way into the modules and/or libs you need.

I don't have any joy using the form

```
$('myselector').highcharts(...)
```

Replacing them with

```
Highcharts.chart('myselector', ...)
```

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra plugin or modification in your webpack config file. Just follow these steps:

install typings file for highcharts using this:

`npm install --save @types/highcharts`

change your import statements to following:

`import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsMore = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);`

Answer (score 1):

For me only this method is working with webpack(and was working with browserify as well):

**global.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery';

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

**app.js**

```
import './globals';
import 'angular';
import 'highcharts';
// ...
```

I don't know why `webpack.ProvidePlugin` works fine with `AngularJS` but not with `highcharts`.

My config was looking like:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery', // for using with AngularJS
    _: 'underscore',
    moment: 'moment'
})

// I've also tried this but without luck:
{
  test: require.resolve('highcharts'),
  loader: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
}
```

Comment: also you can import jQuery with `webpack.ProvidePlugin` and only declare `global.$ = global.jQuery = $`. I don't know why but `global.$` declaration doesn't work via `ProvidePlugin`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the package name as used during `npm install`:

`import highcharts from 'highcharts-release';`

Comment: Did the install work? Are the files there in the node_modules directory?

Answer (score 0):

i am working with AngulrJS, ES6, Webpack and Babel. it took me a while to find it but i ended up using expose on highchart.

this is what i did:

```
npm install highcharts --save

import 'expose?highcharts!highcharts/highcharts';
```

only import as shown, no need for any thing else.

and then you can simple use highchart in your controller (without adding it as a dependency)

Answer (score 0):

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import 'highcharts-ng'  //add this line if you wish to use highcharts angular directive
```

And then add a new rule in the webpack.config.js

```
{
   test: require.resolve('highcharts'),
   use:[{
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'Highcharts'
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel Mix (on top of Webpack) in case this helps anyone out.

**App.js**

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import highchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';

window.Highcharts = highcharts;

highchartsMore(Highcharts);
```

This works with:

```
"highcharts": "^9.3.2",
```